# how to compare two columns with different number of row

Tags: r

I have 2 large data frame that look:

```
  V1            Tri1    Tri2    Tri3    Tri4
200610-214      A G     A G     G G     G G
2010-08-Y       A G     A G     G G     G G
exm-IND22       I I     I I     I I     D D
exm-rs10223     A A     C C     C C     C C
exm-rs16933415  G G     A G     A A     A A
exm-rs2172802   A A     A A     A A     A G
exm-rs2284176   A A     A A     A A     A A
exm-rs2681019   A A     C C     A A     A A
exm-rs2853931   A A     A A     A A     A A
exm-rs3131786   C C     C C     C G     C C
exm-rs3177928   G G     G G     G G     G G
exm-rs7067387   A G     A G     A A     A A
exm-rs950063    G G     A A     G G     G G
```

and

```
V1          
200610-214      
2010-08-Y       
exm-rs10223    
exm-rs2172802   
exm-rs2681019   
exm-rs2853931   
exm-rs3131786
```

I want to find column of second data frame in first data frame and get new data frame that should look

```
V1              Tri1    Tri2    Tri3    Tri4
200610-214      A G     A G     G G     G G
2010-08-Y       A G     A G     G G     G G
exm-rs10223     A A     C C     C C     C C
exm-rs2172802   A A     A A     A A     A G
exm-rs2681019   A A     C C     A A     A A
exm-rs2853931   A A     A A     A A     A A
exm-rs3131786   C C     C C     C G     C C
```

How i can do it?

Comment: see `?merge` ... or the `*_join` functions in the `dplyr` package ...

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, as using a merge would be overkill in this case.

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* use a merge, in this case there's a much simpler solution:

```
df1[df1$V1 %in% df2$V1, ]
```

where `df1` is your main dataset, and `df2` is the dataset with the values you want to keep.